AG-Grid - Pivoting - Horizontal and vertical columns
We are trying to build a grid that would contain columns both horizontally and vertically. Like the below grid.

We would have multiple header columns. User should have an option to add and remove the title columns. We would also have vertical columns that would contain titles. In the center we would have a combination of data that would belong both to vertical column and horizontal column.
We should be able to update the data of header columns as well as the data, on the fly without re-rendering the entire grid when we get a WebSocket update.
We would also need grouping of rows as shown in the bottom 4th row in horizontal column.
We would also need filtering and show, hide columns basing on user preference.
The data set would be large. there could be 100+ horizontal columns and more than 1000 vertical columns, which user could add more to, on the fly or gets added via WebSocket update.
One last thing. This is more or less a data entry sheet. So, users would enter a value and press enter. On which the data should be saved and the control should be passed down to the next row in the same vertical column.
Performance is critical here so, the rendering should be done efficiently.
Does the ag-grid support these behaviors?
